# C# - Convert multi-project solutions to 1-1 solution to project

Tags: c#, makefile

Let's say I have a **single** solution file that references **N** project files. There's a 1-N relationship of solution to project files.

How can I make a script that makes **N** solution files, each of which points to a distinct project file?

Example: I've got **A.sln** that points to *a.csproj*, *b.csproj*, and *c.csproj*. What's a good way to make a script that will create two more solution files, **B.sln** and **C.sln**?

Here's what I have in mind:

```
fn(Solution f) 
{
   projectArray = f.getAllProjects;
   for each project in projectArray
   {
     Solution s = new Solution(project); // makes new solution with name and 
                                         // reference to project
     s.copySettings(f); // copy all of f minus the project references
     s.save(); // save new Solution
   }

  delete f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to parse .sln file manually. You can read about .sln file format in the article [Hack the Project and Solution Files](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vshacks_chap1/index.html?page=4)